# Send transactional email with SendGrid in cloud functions Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I followed this tutorial: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sendgrid-v3-nodejs-transactional-email-cloud-function/ to send transantional emails. The next function was working normally but with the new update of the google cloud functions https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloud-firestore has stopped working. What should I change?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.firestoreEmail = functions.firestore
.document('mensajes/{mensajeId}')
.onCreate(event => {

    const mensajeId = event.params.mensajeId;

    const db = admin.firestore()

    return db.collection('mensajes').doc(mensajeId)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {

            const mensaje = doc.data()

            const msg = {
                to: 'xx@xx.com',
                from: 'zz@zz.com',
                subject: 'Subject',
                templateId: 'myTemplateID',
                substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
                substitutions: {

                    nombre: mensaje.nombre,
                    telefono: mensaje.telefono,
                    email: mensaje.email,
                    mensaje: mensaje.mensaje

                }
            };

            return sgMail.send(msg)
        })
        .then(() => console.log('email sent!'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the release of Cloud Functions 1.0.x , the following has changed for Firestore, as you can deduce form the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?hl=uk#cloud-firestore):

**Before (<= v0.9.1)**

```
exports.dbCreate = functions.firestore.document('notes/{noteId}').onCreate((event) => {
    const newData = event.data.data();
    const param = event.params.noteId;
});
```

**Now (v1.0.0)**

```
exports.dbCreate = functions.firestore.document('notes/{noteId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const newData = snap.data(); 
  const param = context.params.noteId;
});
```

So, in your case, that means your Cloud Function shall be changed to:

```
exports.firestoreEmail = functions.firestore
.document('mensajes/{mensajeId}')
.onCreate(event => {

    const mensajeId = context.params.mensajeId;  // <- Here is the change

    const db = admin.firestore()

    return db.collection('mensajes').doc(mensajeId)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {...
        .....
```

Answer (score -1):

## [Cloud Functions Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid)

#### SendGrid Tutorial

This tutorial demonstrates using Cloud Functions to send emails through the SendGrid platform, receive SendGrid analytics data via webhooks, and load the analytics data into Google BigQuery for analysis.

#### Objectives

- Create a SendGrid account.
- Write and deploy two HTTP Cloud Functions.
- Write and deploy one Background Cloud Function.
- Send an email from the deployed function via SendGrid.
- Receive analytics data from SendGrid via webhooks.
- Load SendGrid analytics data into BigQuery for analysis.

[image]