# How To Fix "Unknown error status: Error: The uid must be a non-empty string with at most 128 characters." in Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to create a user in my firebase app by passing the data from the UI to a callable function where I

1. create a user account using email password then
2. add a display name then create a profile in a user collection then
3. send a user confirmation email but I get the error 
   `Unknown error status: Error: The uid must be a non-empty string with at most 128 characters.
   at new HttpsError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:102:19)
   at admin.auth.createUser.then.then.then.catch.error (/srv/index.js:41:12)
   at <anonymous>`

```
const db = admin.firestore();
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{
  return admin.auth().createUser({
    email: data.email,
    password: data.password,
    displayName: data.displayName,
  }).then(user =>{
    return db.doc('users/'+user.uid).set({
      email: data.email,
      displayName:data.displayName,
      type:data.type,
      organization:data.organization
    });
  })
  .then(user=>{
    let uid = user.uid;
    if (data.type === "admin"){
      return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid,{
        isAdmin: true,
      })
    }else{
      return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid,{
        isAdmin: false,
      })
    }
  })
  .then(user =>{ 
    return user.sendEmailVerification();
  })
  .catch(error =>{
     new functions.https.HttpsError(error);
  });
})
```

and this is my code on my React JS front end

```
    let createUser = functions.httpsCallable('createUser')
    createUser({
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      displayName:this.state.name,
      type:this.state.type,
      organization:this.state.organization
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Comment: What exactly is `user` in your second `then` callback? I suspect it is not what you think it is.  Have you tried adding debug log statements to verify that everything is what you expect at each stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
return db.doc('users/'+user.uid).set({
  email: ....});
})
.then(user => { // here, user is undefined})
```

the value of `user` (i.e. the *fulfillment value*, or, in other words, the argument you pass to the first callback function you pass to the then method) **is undefined** since the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference.html#set) method returns a "non-null Promise containing void".

You need to save the value of `uid` in a variable in the previous `then()`, as shown in the code below.

---

Note also that, by doing,

```
  .then(user =>{ 
    return user.sendEmailVerification();
  })
```

firstly you get the same problem than above (the value of `user` is undefined), but, in addition, in the Admin SDK there isn't a `sendEmailVerification()` method, which is a method of the client JavaScript SDK.

You can use the [`generateEmailVerificationLink()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#generateEmailVerificationLink) method of the Admin SDK and send the link by email (from the Cloud Function) to the user, through Sendgrid for example.

```
const db = admin.firestore();
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{

  let userUid;

  return admin.auth().createUser({
    email: data.email,
    password: data.password,
    displayName: data.displayName,
  }).then(user =>{
    userUid = user.uid;
    return db.doc('users/'+userUid).set({
      email: data.email,
      displayName:data.displayName,
      type:data.type,
      organization:data.organization
    });
  })
  .then(()=>{
    if (data.type === "admin"){
      return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userUid,{
        isAdmin: true,
      })
    }else{
      return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userUid,{
        isAdmin: false,
      })
    }
  })
  .then(() =>{ 
    //You may use the generateEmailVerificationLink() method, see
    //https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#generateEmailVerificationLink

    const actionCodeSettings = ....
    return admin.auth()
       .generateEmailVerificationLink(data.email, actionCodeSettings)
  })
  .then(link => {
     //The link was successfully generated.
     //Send an email to the user through an email service

     //See https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation

     //or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205390/send-transactional-email-with-sendgrid-in-cloud-functions-firebase/50248871
  })
  .catch(error =>{
       throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message);
  });
})
```

Comment: how do I send the user object back to the user ?

Comment: Actually, I think I was too fast when proposing to send the verification email from the front-end with the `sendEmailVerification()` method, because indeed you cannot get the new `user` object in the front end. So you need to do that in the back-end, in the Cloud Function, by generating the link with `generateEmailVerificationLink()` and sending it from the Cloud Function. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I was thinking of sending the user object back (with all values ) to the user with their auth claims and sign in the users... How can it be done?

Comment: From your question I understood that this action was going to be done by a kind of admin user, and not by the new user itself. Because if you want that to be done by the user itself, nearly everything can be done from the front end, **apart from setting the custom claims**. So you could create the user, send the verification mail from the front-end and only keep in the CF the custom claims attribution. Actually there are a lot of possible scenarios for such a user creation workflow....

Comment: BTW is the implementation of returning the error object done right ?? I can't seem to get the appropriate error at the UI

Comment: You need to throw the error and add a code, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https.HttpsError. See the update for an example.

Comment: I have generated some errors (Knowingly ) but can't see the error in the UI console.log

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client

Comment: Like instead of generating my own error... I want to use the error that comes from the function i.e A user with that email exists

Comment: With   .catch(error =>{}) you catch the errors of all the then() above so you should be able to do that.

Comment: I have tried `.catch(error =>{
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error);
  });` and I'm getting `Error: INTERNAL
    at new HttpsErrorImpl (index.cjs.js?001a:59)` in the UI log